# Cannot find package "golang.org/x/net/context" in any of:

Tags: go, ubuntu-18.04

So I'm trying to run my code and I'm receiving the below errors. So then I open another terminal and try installing the dependencies and it's saying it is unable to locate the package on all of them I've searched and searched for answers for like 2 hours now and tried everything I can with no luck at all.
I am using Golang version 1.7 and I'm running it on Ubuntu 18.04.

GOPATH = /home/baller/go

Heres the imports:

```
import ( 
    "bufio" 
    "encoding/json" 
    "errors" 
    "flag" 
    "fmt" 
    "log" 
    "io/ioutil" 
    "net" 
    "net/http" 
    "os" 
    "os/exec" 
    "path/filepath" 
    "runtime" 
    "strconv" 
    "strings" 
    "golang.org/x/net/context" 
    "golang.org/x/oauth2" 
    "google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"
)
```

Errors:

```
like_video.go:22:9: cannot find package "golang.org/x/net/context" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/golang.org/x/net/context (from $GOROOT)
    /home/baller/go/src/golang.org/x/net/context (from $GOPATH)
like_video.go:23:9: cannot find package "golang.org/x/oauth2" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/golang.org/x/oauth2 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/baller/go/src/golang.org/x/oauth2 (from $GOPATH)
like_video.go:24:9: cannot find package "google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/baller/go/src/google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3 (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: The context package is just `"context"`

Comment: when I do pip install context I'm getting this: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement context.viewer (from context) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for context.viewer (from context)`

Comment: And, as is mentioned above, you need `$GOPATH` defined. Commonly, in your working directory `mkdir -p go/src/<your-sources>; export GOPATH=$PWD/go; go get ./...`. Once you've defined imports in your code, you need to pull the imports packages from github and `$GOPATH` (unless you're using modules) is required.

Comment: `pip` is for Python but the code you've included is Go(lang) and it uses a different set of tools.

Comment: You also claim to be using go 1.7, but your error message reads `/usr/lib/go-1.10/`? There's a lot of confusion in this question.

Comment: Have you ever done "go get -u golang.org/x/net/context"

Comment: If you want to use your programm in production you should NEVER use an not supported version. After Version 1.7 there are many security fixes. So if even if you would able to compile you would have security issues.

Answer (score 6):

First your Go version is outdated. It is not a good idea to use an old version, because there were a lot of security fixes until the 1.7 release.

Your go code is also outdated, because the context package moved from the experimental part (the x inside the path) into the standard library. So the import path for the context pacakge changed. To fix that you should run `go fix` on your project.

More information you can find at: https://golang.org/cmd/fix/

There are also some other packages missing. Just read the errors and they tell you. For all missing packages you should run `go get`.

So you have following things to do:

- update your Go installation
- run `go fix`
- install the missing packages with running `go get`